# jquery substring a long string between two words

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have one string

```
var string = "T-shirt SKU-TST071815-BLACKTHAMB (Code: 111R)"
```

i want following ourput

```
var output  = "TST071815-BLACKTHAMB"
```

"**T-shirt SKU-TST071815-BLACKTHAMB (Code: 111R)**" is everytime genrated by database and changes everytime , but format remains same.
so i want to extract a string in between "SKU-" and "(Code"

i tried wirth replace function , but result is not as desgred..plz help

Comment: String manipulation has nothing to do with jQuery.  Only javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to retrieve the `SKU-` from the string, up to the next word boundary, something like this:

```js
var string = "T-shirt SKU-TST071815-BLACKTHAMB (Code: 111R)"

var re = /SKU-[\w-]+/gi;
var sku = re.exec(string);
console.log(sku);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to substring, finding the index of the left and right delimiters you specified.  The first delimited being shifted over the length of the delimiter (4 in this case).

```js
var string = "T-shirt SKU-TST071815-BLACKTHAMB (Code: 111R)";

console.log(
  string.substring(string.indexOf('SKU-') + 4, string.indexOf(' (Code'))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First split at the position where `SKU-` starts using [look-ahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and get second half, then split based on space and get the first element.

```js
var string = "T-shirt SKU-TST071815-BLACKTHAMB (Code: 111R)"

var sku = string
  // split at position where SKU-1 starts
  .split(/(?=SKU-)/)
  // get last string(Second half)
  .pop()
  // split based on space and get first element
  .split(' ')[0];

console.log(sku);
```